# How to add svg file into code? Visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, svg

I need to add an svg in the following format:

```
<svg class="xxx" width="x" height="x" viewBox="xx" fill="xx" xmlns="xxx">
   <path fill-rule="xx" clip-rule="xx" d="192 1920192 1920129.210291090291 192012" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

How do I get an svg file and get it into the format above? SVG code above is in a .cshtml file.  I've tried dragging and dropping the SVG file into code but it turns into an image tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get a svg image in that format. You can use Illustrator, CorellDraw, but if you intend to use it for the web then the best option is to use Inkscape.
On how to add the svg code, if you want to add it to html code, there are many ways to do that. Any of which have pros and cons depending on what you want to do with the svg.

1-You can simply embed the code within the html file. Open the svg in Visual Studio and copy then paste into a div tag in the html code.
Like this:
[image]

2- You can use the img tag and call the svg file like any other image.
Like this:
[image]

3- You can use Object to call the svg file into html but I really never use this method and I don't know how to do it this way. But 1 min of Google search probably knows how to.